# conky config issue with wheight

Tags: opensuse, gnome3, conky

I copied this config https://www.gefoo.org/simple-conky-configuration-plainconky.html and I know it worked out just fine when I start testing it. But suddenly I can't see it full. And I did not make any change at all!

**Original conf**:

[image: original conf]

In the original you can see how the bottom is cut out.

**Edited by me**:

[image: edited by me]

In the one I edited you can't tell that anything is wrong because the font size, but the top five of processes running is cut out.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is it cut at the bottom or on the right or both? Could you post a screenshot with a dark background? We can't really see it at the moment.

Comment: it's cut at the bottom... will add other screen shot. :D